# Usage of "the" prefix where it doesn't seem to be grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I've noticed 2 instances of usage of a  ***the*** prefix where it doesn't seem to correspond with standard usage of English.

> **The flu**

I'd expect *a flu* or just *flu*:

- He caught a flu
- She's infected with flu
- They have flu

Instead, the common usage seems to be the flu, such as [Is It a Cold or the Flu? How to Tell the Difference](https://symptoms.webmd.com/cold-flu-map/difference-cold-or-flu) or [Dispelling misinformation about the flu vaccine](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/10-flu-myths) (with more examples inside).

> **The movies**

Mid-way of writing my argument for this one, I've noticed it had been [asked and answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61446/why-go-to-the-movies-and-not-go-to-a-movie), albeit I was not convinced why "the movies" as a way to describe walking to a cinema to watch a movie, stayed as an idiomatic phrase today (a relic from a past usage of "moving pictures") and wasn't replaced by the simpler, singular form of *a movie*.

Happy to hear your thoughts for this one here or in the original thread.

Comment: This has been asked and answered here easily a hundred times.

Comment: You may get better explanations at ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @HotLicks links would be helpful (I cited the only one I found, for only one of the usages)

Comment: @GEdgar seems like here is more appropriate

Comment: Influenza spreads around the world in yearly outbreaks. Although there may be differences in these outbreaks, the differences fade beneath the commonalities. Influenza seems like one thing, advancing, striking its victims and retreating--and then returning. It seems like one particular thing, a definite thing, and thus the definite article.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flu?q=flu

Comment: @CJDennis it displays the usage, doesn't explain the _why_

Comment: @OferZelig "Why" is usually a very bad question to ask in linguistics because the answer is usually "It just is".